# React onClick event on component

Tags: javascript, events, reactjs

I have a React component called `<SensorList />` that has many child `<SensorItem />`s (another React component). I want to be able to declare an `onClick` event on each `<SensorItem />` from within `<SensorList />`. I have tried doing the following:

```
sensorSelected: function(sensor) {
    console.log('Clicked!');
},

render: function() {
    var nodes = this.state.sensors.map(function(sensor) {
        return (
            <SensorItem onClick={ this.sensorSelected } />
        );
    }.bind(this));

    return (
        <div className="sensor-list">
            { nodes }
        </div>
    );
}
```

Needless to say, I do not get any "Clicked!" coming up in my console. The React inspector in Chrome indicates that an `onClick` event is registered, with the above function body as it should be.

I conclude, therefore, that I can't register `onClick` events on the actual `<SensorItem />` tags (I'm not sure why this is, however). How do I go about achieving this otherwise?

Answer (score 139, accepted):

This depends on your SensorItem component's definition.
Because SensorItem isn't a *native DOM element* but, like you said, another React component, **onClick** as defined here is simply a property of that component. What you need to do is, inside of the SensorItem component pass the onClick prop to an DOM component's onClick event:

```
var SensorItem = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div className="SensorItem" onClick={this.props.onClick}>
       ...
      </div>
    );
  }
});
```

Comment: Got it, I had thought perhaps that a component automatically passed on any events to the main DOM Node (`getDOMNode()`), but there's no reason this should be the case.

Comment: I had thought, assumed, was certain that those geniuses at Facebook would've thought it would be convenient. Not convenient enough, I guess.

Comment: To add to that, you can pass through *all* props to the main DOM Node fairly easily with argument destructuring syntax like this:

```
const SensorItem = ({...props}) => {
  return (
    <div className="SensorItem" {...props}>
    ...
    </div>
  );
}
```

That makes it future-proof if you need to add onDoubleClick, onKeyDown, etc.

Answer (score 28):

### Problem

The problem, as being explained in another answer, is that `onClick` on a `<SensorItem>` React component (contrary to native DOM element like `<div>` or `<p>`) is treated as passing of component property, and not of a DOM event handler. And as most likely your `<SensorItem>` component doesn't declare `onClick` property, that property value simply gets lost.

### Solution

The most straightforward solution is to add `onClick` property explicitly on `SensorItem` component, then pass it to the root DOM element of that component:

```
function SensorItem({ prop1, prop2, onClick }) {
  (...)

  return (
    <p onClick={onClick}>
      (...)
    </p>
  );
}
```

But the solution that usually works best for me is to group all the undefined component's properties using object destructuring notation, then pass them all to the root DOM element within that component. This way you can pass `onClick`, `onHover`, `className` etc. without needing to define separate properties for each one of them:

```
function SensorItem({ prop1, prop2, ...rootDOMAttributes }) {
  (...)

  return (
    <p {...rootDOMAttributes}>
      (...)
    </p>
  );
}
```

No matter which of the two approaches you use, the handler will now work, as it'll now be attached to the root DOM element of `SensorItem`:

```html
<SensorItem onClick={...} />
```

Comment: what would be the type for `onClick` in TS?