# onclick function is not working in react native application

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm new to react native. I wrote the following code to call a function, if a user clicks on a text.

```
var login = React.createClass({
     openPopup: function(){
        console.log("function called");
     },
     render: function(){
        return (
           <View onClick={this.openPopup}>
              <Text>
                 Login
              </Text>
           </View>
        );
     }
});
```

Is there anything wrong in the above code? If I click the login text, I'm not getting any feedback in the console.

**EDIT**
This question is react native specific. Not a duplicate of any other question in Stack Overflow.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [React onClick event on component](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28268835/react-onclick-event-on-component)

Comment: That question is for just react.js. I can't use div element in react native. Instead of it I'm using View and text tags. This question in react native specific. The answer in that question is not helping me.

Comment: The problem wasn't specific to React native, the general form of both solutions has been: the component doesn't accept a click handler. I marked it as a possible duplicate because I wasn't sure which React Native components do.

Comment: This shouldn't be a duplicate. You need to use a specific component (`TouchableOpacity`) in react native to get the onClick functionality, while in react you can use `onClick` on most native (i.e. non custom) components.

Comment: This is amazing. There's an onClick attribute, it doesn't do anything at all, but it also doesn't give you any warning or error when you set it on something and expect it to work. Terrible API.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Try this-

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress={this.openPopup}> 
    <View> <Text>...</Text> </View> 
</TouchableOpacity>
```

Comment: When I use Nesting `TouchableOpacity`. the inner `TouchableOpacity` component doesn't clickable. could you please help!!

Answer (score 46):

You need to use one of the following wrapper components. Below are just the ones listed, which are available cross-platform.

### [TouchableHighlight](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/touchablehighlight.html#content)

```
<TouchableHighlight onPress={this.openPopup}>
    <View>...</View>
</TouchableHighlight>
```

### [TouchableOpacity](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/touchableopacity.html#content)

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress={this.openPopup}>
    <View>...</View>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

### [TouchableWithoutFeedback](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/touchablewithoutfeedback.html#content)

```
<TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={this.openPopup}>
    <View>...</View>
</TouchableWithoutFeedback>
```

---

Note the above are on their way to being deprecated. Check out [Pressable](https://reactnative.dev/docs/pressable)

Answer (score 0):

```
layout_Provider= () => {

 this.rowRenderer= this.rowRenderer.bind(this);}
}

<TouchableOpacity
 style={styles.container}
 onPress={this.GoToEditActivity.bind(this, data.student_id, data.student_name, data.student_class, data.student_subject)}
 >

 <Image style={styles.image}
 source={{uri: data.student_pic}}/>
 {/*source={{uri: "http://homepages.cae.wisc.edu/~ece533/images/barbara.png"}}/>*/}

 <View style={styles.textContainer}>
 <Text style={styles.name}> {data.student_id}</Text>
 <Text style={styles.email}> {data.student_name}</Text>
 </View>
 <View style={styles.textContainer}>
 <Text style={styles.name}> {data.student_class}</Text>
 <Text style={styles.email}> {data.student_subject}</Text>
 </View>

</TouchableOpacity>
GoToEditActivity(student_id, student_name, student_class, student_subject) {

 console.log("GoToEditActivity ---------------------- student_id " + student_id);
 console.log("GoToEditActivity ---------------------- student_name " + student_name);
 console.log("GoToEditActivity ---------------------- student_class " + student_class);
 console.log("GoToEditActivity ---------------------- student_subject " + student_subject);

 this.props.navigation.navigate('EditActivity', {

 ID : student_id,
 NAME : student_name,
 CLASS : student_class,
 SUBJECT : student_subject,

 });
}
```