# How do I rerender a functional component?

Tags: reactjs

Here, I've tied a click event to the child component to get the parent component to re-render. According to the official solution, there is no way to use the forUpdate() method in the function component, but the compromise is to use setState to re-render. However, the parent component does not rerender when clicked. In the function component, what method is used for the child component to rerender the parent component?

Here is the subcomponent code:

```
export default function Refresh({ refresh }: Props) {
    return (
        <RefreshContainer>
            <RefreshContent onClick={ refresh }>
                <RefreshIcon color={ '#4F7DAF' } className={ 'icon-refresh' } size={ '16px' } marginRight={ '4px' }/>
                <RefreshSpan color={ '#4F7DAF' } text={ '点击刷新' } marginRight={ '4px' } />
                <RefreshSpan color={ '#999999' } text={ '换一批内容' } />
            </RefreshContent>
        </RefreshContainer>
    )
}
```

Here is the parent component code:

```
export default () => {
    const [ refresh, setRefresh ] = useState<boolean>(false)
    const update = useCallback(() => {
        // test
        document.querySelector('.found-scroll-container')!.scrollTo({
            top: 0,
            left: 0,
            behavior: 'smooth'
        })
        setRefresh(refresh => !refresh)
    }, [])
    return (
        <div className={ 'found-scroll-container' }>
            <div className={ 'found-scroll-content' }>
                <div className={ 'container-padding' }>
                    <Carousel type={ '2' }/>
                    <Type />
                </div>
                <div className={ 'recommend-container-padding' }>
                    <Recommend quantity={ '6' }/>
                    <RecommendNewMusic />
                    <HotWindVane />
                    <Radio/>
                </div>
                <Refresh refresh={ update } />
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

***After clicking RefreshContainer, let the parent component rerender, the effect should be the same as window.reload() method. How do you do that? Thank you very much!***

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React onClick event on component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28268835/react-onclick-event-on-component)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that your `onClick` event on `<RefreshContent onClick={ refresh }>` will not trigger because `onClick` is a DOM event but the `RefreshContent` is just a react component so for `RefreshContent`, `onClick` will be passed as React props.

What you should do is in the `RefreshContent` attach the `onClick` to the native DOM element.

**For Example**

Attach the event to the DOM element

```js
const RefreshContent = props => (
  <div onClick={props.onClick}>{props.children}</div>
);
```

This will cause the `onClick` event to trigger and your state in Parent component will be updated.

https://codesandbox.io/s/infallible-roentgen-7nczb?file=/src/components/Refresh.jsx:606-696

Comment: The state can change with a click, but the parent component cannot be rerendered!

Comment: i have updated the code sandbox with the scrolling example as in your code. https://codesandbox.io/s/suspicious-ride-yenx6

Comment: if you mentioned that state can be changed and callback is executed. then your scroll bar should go to the top. what issue are u facing? is it callback not executing? Or component not re-rendered when state is changed?

Answer (score 0):

@m5khan Thank you for your answer! RefreshContent is packed in styled - components, click events can be triggered, and the state will also be changed by clicking!

```
const RefreshContent = styled.div`
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    font-size: 0;
    text-align: center
`
```