# mouseEnter and mouseLeave work on HTML elements, but not React components?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-state, mouseenter

First time making a React site (using Gatsby).

#### What I *want* to happen

On my index page, I'm trying make a `Note` component appear when the mouse hovers over a `Term` component.

#### What *is* happening

When I add `onMouseEnter` and `onMouseLeave` directly to the `Term` component, the `Note` never appears. However, if I use a native html element (`span` in example code below) instead of `<Term/>`, the `Note` does appear.

Does it have something to do with the arrow function?

- Replacing `() => setShowNoteB(true)` with `console.log("in TermB")` (sort of) works.
- But using `onMouseEnter={setShowNoteB(true)}` results in an infinite loop error.

Is it related to how I'm composing the components? or is a it a limitation of the `useState` hook?
What I'm doing here seems fairly simple/straightforward, but again, I'm new to this, so maybe there's some rule that I don't know about.

#### Example code

##### Index page

```
//index.js

import * as React from 'react';
import { useState } from 'react';
import Term from '../components/term';
import Note from '../components/note';


const IndexPage = () => {
  const [showNoteA, setShowNoteA] = useState(false);
  const [showNoteB, setShowNoteB] = useState(false);

  return (
    <>
      <h1
      >
        <span
          onMouseEnter={() => setShowNoteA(true)}
          onMouseLeave={() => setShowNoteA(false)}
        > TermA* </span>
        {" "} doesn't behave like {" "}
        <Term word="TermB" symbol="†"
          onMouseEnter={() => setShowNoteB(true)}
          onMouseLeave={() => setShowNoteB(false)}
        />
      </h1>

      {showNoteA ? <Note> <p>This is a note for TermA.</p> </Note> : null}
      {showNoteB ? <Note> <p>This is a note for TermB.</p> </Note> : null}
    </>
  );
};

export default IndexPage
```

##### Term component

```
// term.js

import React from 'react';

const Term = ({ word, symbol }) => {

  return (
    <div>
      <span>{word}</span>
      <span>{symbol}</span>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Term;
```

##### Note component

```
// note.js

import * as React from 'react';

const Note = ({ children })=> {
  return (
    <div>
      {children}
    </div>
  )
};

export default Note;
```

Comment: You're passing these props to your Term component but you aren't using them. At runtime, <Term> is replace by a <div> that doesn't have the hover events assigned to it. For this to work as expected, your Term component needs to look like this: https://codesandbox.io/s/angry-glitter-gqf99?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Ah. That makes sense. Thanks. If you post this as an answer, I will accept it.

Comment: Duplicate: [React onClick event on component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28268835/react-onclick-event-on-component)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use Components in your JSX, as opposed to (lowercase) HTML tags, any attribute is only passed as prop and has no further effect directly.

```
<Term
  word="TermB" symbol="†"
  onMouseEnter={() => setShowNoteB(true)}
  onMouseLeave={() => setShowNoteB(false)}
/>
```

You need to grab the passed prop and assign it to an actual HTML element in the Component's JSX, like this:

```
const Term = ({ word, symbol, onMouseEnter, onMouseLeave }) => {
  return (
    <div onMouseEnter={onMouseEnter} onMouseLeave={onMouseLeave}>
      <span>{word}</span> <span>{symbol}</span>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Solution with `useEffect`, `useRef`, `forwardRef` and `addEventListener/removeEventListener`:

**App.js**

```
import React, { useRef } from 'react';

import Term from './Term';

export default function App() {
  const ref = useRef({});

  return (
    <div>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,{' '}
      <Term ref={ref} word="consectetur" symbol="†" /> adipiscing elit. Morbi
      laoreet <Term ref={ref} word="lacus" /> in dui vestibulum, nec imperdiet
      augue vulputate.
    </div>
  );
}
```

If you want to add other terms, just create a new Term component and add the `ref`, `word`, `symbol` (optional) props.

**Term.js**

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, forwardRef } from 'react';

import Note from './Note';

function Term({ word, symbol }, ref) {
  const [isHovered, setHovered] = useState(false);
  const [currentTerm, setCurrentTerm] = useState('');
  const [currentSymbol, setCurrentSymbol] = useState('');

  useEffect(() => {
    if (ref.current && word) {
      ref.current[word].addEventListener('mouseover', handleMouseover);
      ref.current[word].addEventListener('mouseout', handleMouseout);

      return () => {
        ref.current[word].removeEventListener('mouseover', handleMouseover);
        ref.current[word].removeEventListener('mouseout', handleMouseout);
      };
    }
  }, [ref.current, word]);

  const handleMouseover = () => {
    setHovered(true);
    setCurrentTerm(word);
    setCurrentSymbol(symbol);
  };

  const handleMouseout = () => {
    setHovered(false);
    setCurrentTerm('');
    setCurrentSymbol('');
  };

  return (
    <>
      <span ref={(elem) => (ref.current[word] = elem)}>
        {word}
      </span>
      {isHovered ? <Note word={currentTerm} symbol={currentSymbol} /> : null}
    </>
  );
}

const forwarded = forwardRef(Term);
export default forwarded;
```

**Note.js**

```
import React from 'react';

export default function Note({ word, symbol }) {

  const checkTerm = (term) => {
    switch (term) {
      case 'consectetur':
        return `definition`;
      case 'lacus':
        return `definition`;
      default:
        return null;
    }
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <p>
        {word} {symbol ? symbol : '-'}
      </p>
      <p>{checkTerm(word)}</p>
    </div>
  );
}
```

**Demo:** [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-y4y6vg)

Comment: Merci, I see that works in the demo. 

But why is `useState` and `onMouseEnter` sufficient for the html element case and not in the case of the react component?

Comment: @infieri check my edited answer with useRef, forwardRef, EventListener... Otherwise look at Chris's answer with onMouseEnter/onMouseLeave