# How to fire up onClick function in inner div element

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, node.js, onclick

I'm trying to build a chats page where I can add users like in WhatsApp and make every click on each of the chats respond according to the selected chat.

```html
    <div id="list_chat">
      {contacts.map(contact => (
        <ContactBlock
          receiver={contact.receiver}
          username={contact.username}
          displayName={contact.displayName}
          password={contact.password}
          profilePic={contact.profilePic}
          time={contact.time}
          lastmessage={contact.lastmessage}
          key={contact.username}
        />
      ))}
    </div>
```

```js
function ContactBlock({ receiver, username, displayName, password, profilePic, time, lastmessage}) {
  const handleClick = () => {
    console.log(`Clicked on contact with username:`,);
  };
```

```html
  return (
    <div className="block" id="contact_block" onClick={handleClick}>
      <div className="imgbx">
        <img src={profilePic} alt="not found" className="cover" />
      </div>
      <div className="details">
        <div className="listhead">
          <h4>{displayName}</h4>
          <p className="time">{time}</p>
        </div>
        <div className="message_p">
          <p>{lastmessage}</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default ContactBlock;
```

i cant activate the onClick on ContactBlock but it works on the "list_chat" div.
when i click on the ContactBlock it refers to the "list_chat" div.

Comment: can you clarify more what the issue is?

Comment: Related, is this a duplicate? https://stackoverflow.com/q/28268835/125981   ALSO note you have `id="contact_block"` so there **should be ONLY ONE of these on your rendered page**. Otherwise this generates invalid HTML

Answer (score 1):

When you click on a `ContactBlock`, the event might propagate up to the parent div with the id `list_chat`. This is might be due to event capturing.

Add `event.stopPropagation()` in `handleClick` to prevent this behaviour.

```js
const handleClick = (event) => {
  event.stopPropagation();
  console.log(`Clicked on contact with username: ${username}`);
};
```

Alternatively, you can use `addEventListener`, to specify the element order when an event occurs:

visit https://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_addeventlistener_usecapture to see

Comment: Can we perhaps use this reference instead of that other one: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener  OR also include the spec link https://www.w3.org/2003/01/dom2-javadoc/org/w3c/dom/events/EventTarget.html

Comment: they look resourceful, so they can be used as well

Comment: @Kelechi Daniels, i tried this answer and it didnt work..
when i clicked on the "contact_block" div it shows nothing on the console.
i also tried the second solution and it didnt work either, i defined the listner on a component that rendered after the ContactBlock so it could activate the getElementById.

Comment: I have no insight into how you have implemented the solution but @MarkSchultheiss has given some resources that may help you